# Need to retrieve protected page on clicking a link (R Brew)

Tags: r

I am working on a R brew HTML page where I need a link that on click will retrieve a csv from a password protected site. I can create the link easily with something like

```
a href="<%=theURL%>"
```

where theURL contains the URL I need to access. However, I can't pass the login credentials.

There is one way to do it using the

```
http://id:password@http://... syntax,
```

but that won't work on Internet Explorer. So if I set something like that in the a href tag, it won't be recognized by IE.

Another option was to use RCurl, but I only need this external page to be retrieved only if the user clicks on the specific link as the content can be quite large.

I also have this data in a dataframe format in my brew session. A final alternative is that onclick, it will create an xls from the dataframe, save it locally with an unique name and then provide that to the user.

Any suggestions would be very helpful,

Thanks in advance,

- Raj